# Running official Nexus3 Image where script running is enabled

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to start a container of Nexus 3.22.0 where the script running option is automatically enabled.

From this link (https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045220393) I can see that it is possible to enable it **after** I create the image and restart the container, though i'm interested in creating it with that option right away, is this possible?

Possibly a flag or an argument to add the the "docker run...sonatype/nexus3:3.22.0" command.

Somewhere to add the "nexus.scripts.allowCreation=true" option to the command or add it to the end of the /nexus-data/etc/nexus.properties file as it says in the documentation.

Comment: `add it to the end of the /nexus-data/etc/nexus.properties` => you are already giving the solution in you own question.

Comment: @Zeitounator i want to add it while running the nexus container in the "docker run..." command. If i add it manually to the file I'd have to restart the container which is not desired since it takes more time